# Nested loops with signed v.s. unsigned int

Tags: c++, loops, unsigned, signed

Anyone know why during the first iteration for `i`, (i.e outter loop), doesn't go through the 
inner loop?

Figured: that perhaps it might have something to do with the  `signed i` and `unsigned j`

Code:

```
template <class T>
Matrix<T> LinearEquations<T>::backSubstitution(Matrix<T>& a, Matrix<T>& b){

    Matrix<T> s(b);
    for(signed i = a.getRows()-1; i > -1; --i){
        //cout << "Debug: i = " << i << endl;
        //if(i == a.getRows()-1) continue;
        for(unsigned j = i+1; j < a.getRows(); ++j){
            //cout << "Debug: i = " << i << ", j = " << j << endl;
            s(i, 0) = s(i, 0) - (a(i, j) * s(j, 0));
        }
        //cout << "Debug: Hello world" << endl;
        s(i, 0) = s(i, 0) / a(i, i);
        //cout << "Debug: i = " << i << endl;
        //cout << "Debug: Hello world" << endl;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: what is the type and value returned by `a.getRows()`

Comment: the inner loop condition is not getting satisfied for the first time of outer loop.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger, or printing out the values of the variables you are comparing?

Comment: Oh okay! Figured it out ... Easy p' :p

Answer (score 2):

Consider your code:

```
for(signed i = a.getRows()-1; i > -1; --i){
    for(unsigned j = i+1; j < a.getRows(); ++j){
```

During the first iteration, `j` will be set to `a.getRows()-1+1`. Obviously, `a.getRows() < a.getRows()` doesn't hold, so the body of the inner loop is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `a.getRows()` returns `3`. Then `i` starts off as `2`. Then `j` starts off as `3`. The loop `for (j = 3; j < 3; ++j)` executes zero times since the test condition is initially false.

Similar logic applies for other values , unless `a.getRows() - 1` is out of range for `signed int`.